# Is it possible to block light pollution?

Tags: light-pollution

The old theory about seeing stars during the day if you stand i the bottom of a well or chimney is proven wrong because the atmosphere scatters the sunlight and makes it too bright to see the stars through.

But what about during the night in cities? Could it work the other way around and sufficiently block out the city light pollution, making it possible to see stars as if it was a black sky even though you were in the middle of a city? And if so what would be the minimum height acquired from the well/chimney and how big a diameter would it be able to have while still blocking out the light pollution?

Comment: It can work (one tip to minimizing light pollution is to [get in the shade](http://www.spaceanswers.com/astronomy/ten-tips-to-minimise-light-pollution/)), but I don't know the calculations of it (or if anyone *has* done so).

Comment: It certainly can't help block lights that are more than a few meters from you. Light pollution isn't just "there's glare in my eyes" -- it's "the better part of the atmosphere is *glowing*."

Comment: To add to @ChrisWhite's comment: it depends on atmospheric conditions. If you can, drive or take a train to somewhere quiet away from local streetlights, maybe 50km to 100km from a big city, and look towards the city at night: in most atmospheric conditions you'll find you can see the glow that Chris is talking about, even though the city itself is significantly under the horizon and there is no line-of-sight propagation to you. If you can find a really dark spot and let your eyes acclimatize to the dark thoroughly, you'll find you can see the glow in even the clearest of conditions.

Answer (score 2):

From a physicist point of view it does not help! Pollution is the reflection of light in the atmosphere rather then lights around you. When you step underneath your chimney,  you will still see all the reflection of the light in the atmosphere right above you.

**BUT:** You will of course have a better view of the stars, as your eyes don't have to adjust to the lights around you, thus being more sensitive for any light coming from the stars.

Answer (score 1):

Light pollution (as Chris White said in the comments) is less about glare from lights directly beaming into your eyes and more about the atmosphere itself being lit up and essentially drowning out the stars.  The contrast between a light polluted sky and stars is too low for our eyes to make the stars out.

One way to get around this is to use a filter.  If you choose a filter that focuses on a specific wavelength of light that stars produce a lot of (which can vary from star to star) then you can increase the contrast with the sky and possibly make stars out even in a light polluted sky. Unfortunately, although filters are useful to increase *contrast* of a star against the sky they will also cut down the overall *brightness* (or flux) coming from the star, so you risk making the star too dim to see even against a perfectly black sky.

Answer (score 1):

Light goes as far up as the atmosphere. Hence, To block light pollution you would have to build a tower many miles high to make it seem like there is no light pollution.